# Qt Toolbar sigsegv segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, qt, memory, qt-creator

Debug error: http://puu.sh/3p8zM.png

My toolbar properties:http://puu.sh/3p8Qo.png
My program was running fine until I hit a lot of undo's and now I get this sigsegv     error when debugging :(.

My code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "login.h"
#include <QAction>
#include <QWidget>
#include <qaction.h>

mainwindow::mainwindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::mainwindow)
{
    rPopulate();
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

mainwindow::~mainwindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void mainwindow::rPopulate()
{
    button = new QPushButton();
    button->setText("Message");
    //button->setIconSize(QSize(30,28));
    ui->toolBar->addWidget(button);
}
void mainwindow::rNew()
{

}

void mainwindow::rView()
{

}
 //ui->_menubar->addMenu(tr("&File"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a sigsegv segmentation fault error because I called rPopulate() before ui->setupUi(this);

GOD THAT IS ANNOYING.